# column names not printing when unparsing json using Papa parse

Tags: json, csv, papaparse

Here is the url to json i am trying to unparse using papa parse
https://chronicdata.cdc.gov/api/views/4juz-x2tp/rows.json

When unparse I get the csv output but do not get the headers/column names printed. is there a way to get the column names printed in the csv output

Thanks

Comment: do you need get value via key?

Comment: actual data is coming as an array to key -->'data'